# SQL Server Function Efficiency If Exists

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, function, ssms

I have the following function which returns a bit:

```
Declare @Ret bit
SET @Ret = 0
IF EXISTS ( Select * from tblExclusion where StatusID = 1 and AccountID = @AccountID )
Begin
SET @Ret = 1
End

Return @Ret
```

Now there can be multiple entries for the same AccountID in the table or none at all but only one entry will ever have a "1" status if it exists.

I have to be honest I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to SQL but when called the function seems to take a long time to return. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the query. If you index StatusID and AccountID it should be very fast

Comment: This is a pretty simple query, if it performs slowly perhaps you should evaluate existing indexes on the table or have a DBA evaluate if one may be added.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into the indexing side that you've both mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index may be necessary, reviewing a [sample execution plan](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx) will reveal what index would improve.

If you were to modify your query to:

```
Declare @Ret bit
SET @Ret = 0
IF EXISTS ( Select 1 from tblExclusion where StatusID = 1 and AccountID = @AccountID )
Begin
SET @Ret = 1
End

Return @Ret
```

An `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` would be of the format:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[tblExclusion] ([StatusID],[AccountID])
<optional, INCLUDE ([columns within the select,]) >
GO
```

Types of indexes and how to create them: [Create Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms188783.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it takes a long time to run, then I would suspect that there is no index on the column "AccountID".  Adding an index on that column will probably significantly improve performance.  However, without knowing how tblExclusion is defined, there is no way to be certain of this answer.  Also, adding an index to StatusID will help as well, assuming there are a large number of entries for different StatusIDs.

Also, since you only need to test the existence of the record, you don't need to select every column in tblExclusion.  You could change "*" to "1" or something, though this will not improve performance significantly.

Comment: The select part was the bit I think I had the most questions about and thanks for mentioning the indexing part as well. I'll look into both those points.

Comment: I don't think changing * makes any difference at all with Exists

Comment: @jazza1000 - it doesn't. See my comments to SmartDev's answer, including link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this form

```
Declare @Ret bitSET @Ret = 0
IF EXISTS ( Select top 1 * from tblExclusion(nolock) where StatusID = 1 and AccountID = @AccountID )
Begin
SET @Ret = 1
End

Return @Ret
```

Remember the index's and maintenance can make this work slow.

Comment: Thanks implementing this made some improvement to the execution time.

Comment: What indexes are on that table?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using `select top 1 1 from` instead of `select * from` as in:

```
Declare @Ret bit
SET @Ret = 0
IF EXISTS (Select top 1 1 from tblExclusion where StatusID = 1 and AccountID = @AccountID)
SET @Ret = 1

Return @Ret
```

This way you avoid getting unneeded and probably large data.

Comment: Why must this myth perpetuate? The optimizer was made smart enough to realise that it didn't need to retrieve any actual data to satisfy an `EXISTS(SELECT *` check back in - I want to say SQL Server 6.5? Maybe 7. Certainly, no currently supported version of SQL Server will "get unneeded and probably large data"

Comment: See E.g. [Subqueries with EXISTS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259(v=sql.105).aspx): "The subquery does not actually produce any data"